# Swift 3: How to convert byte array into Data?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I know how to convert int value into data

```
let value: NSInteger = 1
let valueData:Data = Data(buffer: UnsafeBufferPointer(start: &intVal, count: 1))
```

Now I want to do the same with RGB color denoted in the following way `0xRRGGBB`

How can I achieve it? Should I write it as String, e.q. "543621", then convert it into byte array then convert it to Data?

Comment: In Swift 3 you can even initialize the data `let valueData = Data([1])`

Comment: @vadian Could you provide the code snippet how would initialize Data of hex string to get color as data?

Comment: Is your input a (hex) string or an integer?

Comment: @MartinR which one would be more convenient to initliaze it? It does not matter, can be string, can be int, the point is I have to update value on bluetooth peripheral by this hex color so I need to convert it into Data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it would be appropriate to store the color as an `UInt32` instance, in which case you've already posted a method for initializing a `Data` instance from it

```
var pink: UInt32 = 0xCC6699

let pinkData = Data(buffer: UnsafeBufferPointer(start: &pink, count: 1))
print(pinkData.map {$0}) // [153, 102, 204, 0]

print(0x99, 0x66, 0xCC) // 153 102 204
```

As MartinR points out in a comment below, to ensure the hex number representation `0xCC6699` is stored in its little endian representation (even for systems which employ big endian host byte order), the `pink` variable should be initialized as:

```
var pink = UInt32(0xCC6699).littleEndian

// or ...
var pink = UInt32(littleEndian: 0xCC6699)
```

Comment: *Strictly speaking* it should be `var pink = UInt32(0xCC6699).littleEndian` to make the data independent of the host byte order. How knows to which platform Swift will be ported in the future?